# Search for item across characters on WoW account

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way to search across all your characters to see if you have an item on a character, be it learned, in the bank or in inventory? I'm just curious as since I've started playing WoW again I noticed a lot of items have been removed from the game. There's a couple I'd like to search across all the characters I've made since vanilla WoW to see if I possibly have them. It's a bit of a pain to log onto each character, especially a few of my lower leveled ones I made for a weekend but then left alone, to check their bank and I know I'll probably skip over some items when searching their bags (I constantly misplace items on my main in their bags!).

I'm fine with a mod as well if there is no real solution via Blizzard. Worst case scenario I wouldn't mind logging onto each character just so a mod could "read" or "scan" my character for items and then I could somehow search from the mod.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I prefer [Altoholic](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/altoholic.aspx).  You can see and search bags, banks and guild banks across all you characters, but also Altoholic does so many amazing things for multiple characters as well.

For each character you can also see what currencies, bag slots remaining, gear they have, their talent build, if they have mail and how long until it expires, what recipes they have, their reputations...  With 10 alts, I couldn't live without it at this point.

Answer (score 4):

This addon is your answer, you'll have to log onto each character once and check/open all bags and banks first. (Shift+B) when you have your bank open is the fastest way.

http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/bank-items.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [Bagnon addon](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon) includes an option to see any alt's inventory or bank.